# What's wrong with my batch file for unraring with winrar?

Tags: batch-file, winrar

I'm having troubles going from 7zip to Winrar. The batch script goes into every subdir and extracts whatever rar-files in them to D:\Stuff\Testfolder

My current (working) batch file for 7zip looks like this:

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
        FOR %%X in (*.rar) DO (
            "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X" -oD:\Stuff\Testfolder -y
        )
    popd
)
```

However, trying it on Winrar by using the same file with the executable line changed to:

```
 "C:\Program Files\winrar\unrar.exe" x "%%X" D:\Stuff\Testfolder -y
```

Nothing happens. All I get is an output of the current directory.

Anyone have some input on this?

Cheers
Tobbe

Comment: Is the command line syntax of winRar *exactly* the same as 7z's?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see from http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/

Answer (score 0):

Do like this....

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\unrar.exe" x "%%~nX.rar" "D:\Stuff\Testfolder\"
```

[If you want to read more....](http://comptb.cects.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/uncompress_rar.bat_.txt)